# Charset in communication with server

Tags: android

I'm trying to connect with server in Android Application. Just simple post on server, but I want to use e.g. polish types and when I changed charset from UTF-8 to iso8859-2 it didn't helped. Any ideas?

```
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppostreq = new HttpPost("http://simpleserver");
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonMessage.toString());
            se.setContentType("application/json;charset=ISO8859-2");
            se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=ISO8859-2"));
            httppostreq.setEntity(se);
            HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppostreq);
```

Comment: (jsonMessage.toString(), "ISO8859-2"); ?

Comment: I tried it, didn't help

Comment: You should tell something about your server.